# NestedRecyclerView Problem - Last item of the second RecyclerView is duplicated into the first one after the keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm desperate.

I have a nested recycler view. Each outer element has an array of inner elements. A different adapter has been created for the inner elements. I am creating an array of external elements of class "KairosWithEvents", each of which contains internal elements of class "Event". Everything is displayed well. When elements are added, everything is also updated. For testing, I created two objects of the "KairosWithEvent" class. In the first object I have placed two objects of the "Event" class, and in the second - three objects. But when I want to change the EditText value, the keyboard appears. And the last element of the second object appears in the first object. How can I fix it? Objects are not moved or duplicated, but showed incorrectly.

This is what a nestled recycler view looks like initially.

[image]

And this is what a nested recycler view looks like after the keyboard appears. The "Эвент5" element is duplicated to the first element for some reason.

[image]

Here's my code: Outer Adapter:

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static List<Item> items;
    private static RecyclerViewClickInterface listener;
    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool sharedPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    private Context context;

    public EventAdapter() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EventAdapter(List<Item> newItems){
        items = newItems;


    }


    class KairosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        private TextView title;
        private CheckBox iv;
        private RecyclerView rv;

        public KairosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
            rv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvSteaks);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#91b3f2"));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        void bind(KairosWithEvents kairosWithEvents){

            title.setText(kairosWithEvents.kairos.kairosId + " = " + kairosWithEvents.kairos.title);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                    rv.getContext(),
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false);

            List<Item> itemsEvents = new ArrayList<>();

            kairosWithEvents.events.forEach(i -> itemsEvents.add(new Item(Constants.EVENT_KAIROS, i)));


            SubAdapter childAdapter = new SubAdapter(itemsEvents);
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setAdapter(childAdapter);
            rv.setRecycledViewPool(sharedPool);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (listener != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                listener.onItemKairosWithEvents( ((KairosWithEvents) items.get(position).object) );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case Constants.KAIROS:
                return new KairosViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_ex, parent, false));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       switch (getItemViewType(position)){
           case Constants.KAIROS:
               KairosWithEvents kairos = ((KairosWithEvents) items.get(position).object);
               ((KairosViewHolder) holder).bind(kairos);
               break;

       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).type;
    }
}
```

Inner Adapter:

public class SubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

```
private static List<Item> items;


public SubAdapter(List<Item> newItems) {
    items = newItems;
}

static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView title;

    public EventViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc8a8"));
    }

    void bind(Event event){
        title.setText(event.eventId + " = " + event.title);
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case Constants.EVENT_KAIROS:
            return new EventViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_sub, parent, false));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)){
        case Constants.EVENT_KAIROS:
            Event event = (Event) items.get(position).object;
            ((EventViewHolder) holder).bind(event);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return items.get(position).type;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SubAdapter`, remove the `static` keyword from your `items` field:

```
private static List<Item> items;
```

Should be this instead:

```
private List<Item> items;
```

You should make the same change to your outer adapter, but since there's only one of them at a time it doesn't wind up causing issues.

Comment: Man, you saved my life.
Thanks a lot. Thank you so much.